# Deciphering MSDN C++ API calls and structures and calling from VB6

Tags: c++, api, vb6, sip

I'm trying to call a function on TAPI32.dll from a VB6 application. I can't figure out how to specify the information in VB6 and call it. So, this question is asking about help deciphering the C++ related information from MSDN, and calling it from VB6, but I have detailed below our specific usage, in the hope that it helps.

Our application uses a SIP (Session Initializatio Protocol) stack from a company called Dialogic, that allows us to deal with incoming phone calls, read the DDI number (the number the caller dialled), and their Caller ID (the number the caller is calling from), and to deal with that information updating various records in a database based on the DDI and Caller ID. We have multiple DDI's on various VOIP lines / channels pointing to the same computer. This all works perfectly fine.

Under certain circumstances we make outgoing calls to play a WAV file to supervisor's when a guard or carer hasn't made a visit to a certain location, and called in to record their presence. Hence our using the DDI and Caller ID information.

As we have multiple DDI's pointing to one machine we would like to be able to select one of those numbers (The Calling Party Group Number I believe it's called) when making outgoing calls so that when a supervisor receives a call to his mobile, he sees the same number that his employees call into to register their presence at a site.

We believe the information is set on a makelinecall call to TAPI32.dll

We have this declaration ...

```
Declare Function lineMakeCall Lib "TAPI32.DLL" Alias "lineMakeCallA" (ByVal hLine As Long, ByRef lphCall As Long, ByVal lpszDestAddress As String, ByVal dwCountryCode As Long, ByRef lpCallParams As Any) As Long
```

My understanding is that by setting something on the lpCallParams structure, we should be able to specify the CPGN. I just can't figure out how to do it, as I've tended to only provide functionality in my applications that is easily accessible from COM libraries, and DLL's that VB6 can easily access.

The link on this MSDN page is the definition of the lineMakeCall API function - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms735988(v=vs.85).aspx

Showing this C++ structure definition :-

```
LONG WINAPI lineMakeCall(
  HLINE hLine,
  LPHCALL lphCall,
  LPCSTR lpszDestAddress,
  DWORD dwCountryCode,
  LPLINECALLPARAMS const lpCallParams
);
```

The last item, LPLINECALLPARAMS is where we need to specify the information, I believe.

The link on this MSDN page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms735534(v=vs.85).aspx gives this C++ structure definition :-

```
typedef struct linecallparams_tag {
  DWORD          dwTotalSize;
  DWORD          dwBearerMode;
  DWORD          dwMinRate;
  DWORD          dwMaxRate;
  DWORD          dwMediaMode;
  DWORD          dwCallParamFlags;
  DWORD          dwAddressMode;
  DWORD          dwAddressID;
  LINEDIALPARAMS DialParams;
  DWORD          dwOrigAddressSize;
  DWORD          dwOrigAddressOffset;
  DWORD          dwDisplayableAddressSize;
  DWORD          dwDisplayableAddressOffset;
  DWORD          dwCalledPartySize;
  DWORD          dwCalledPartyOffset;
  DWORD          dwCommentSize;
  DWORD          dwCommentOffset;
  DWORD          dwUserUserInfoSize;
  DWORD          dwUserUserInfoOffset;
  DWORD          dwHighLevelCompSize;
  DWORD          dwHighLevelCompOffset;
  DWORD          dwLowLevelCompSize;
  DWORD          dwLowLevelCompOffset;
  DWORD          dwDevSpecificSize;
  DWORD          dwDevSpecificOffset;
  DWORD          dwPredictiveAutoTransferStates;
  DWORD          dwTargetAddressSize;
  DWORD          dwTargetAddressOffset;
  DWORD          dwSendingFlowspecSize;
  DWORD          dwSendingFlowspecOffset;
  DWORD          dwReceivingFlowspecSize;
  DWORD          dwReceivingFlowspecOffset;
  DWORD          dwDeviceClassSize;
  DWORD          dwDeviceClassOffset;
  DWORD          dwDeviceConfigSize;
  DWORD          dwDeviceConfigOffset;
  DWORD          dwCallDataSize;
  DWORD          dwCallDataOffset;
  DWORD          dwNoAnswerTimeout;
  DWORD          dwCallingPartyIDSize;
  DWORD          dwCallingPartyIDOffset;
  DWORD          dwAddressType;
} LINECALLPARAMS, *LPLINECALLPARAMS;
```

The interesting parameters are the dwCallingPartyIDSize and dwCallingPartyIDOffset. 
I can't figure out how to specify the information to pass to them

We have these types set up in VB6 already :-

```
Type LINECALLINFO
  lngTotalSize As Long
  lngNeededSize As Long
  lngUsedSize As Long
  lngLineHandle As Long
  lngLineDeviceID As Long
  lngAddressID As Long
  lngBearerMode As Long
  lngRate As Long
  lngMediaMode As Long
  lngAppSpecific As Long
  lngCallID As Long
  lngRelatedCallID As Long
  lngCallParamFlags As Long
  lngCallStates As Long
  lngMonitorDigitModes As Long
  lngMonitorMediaModes As Long
  DialParams As LINEDIALPARAMS
  lngOrigin As Long
  lngReason As Long
  lngCompletionID As Long
  lmgNumOwners As Long
  lngNumMonitors As Long
  lngCountryCode As Long
  lngTrunk As Long
  lngCallerIDFlags As Long
  lngCallerIDSize As Long
  lngCallerIDOffset As Long
  lngCallerIDNameSize As Long
  lngCallerIDNameOffset As Long
  lngCalledIDFlags As Long
  lngCalledIDSize As Long
  lngCalledIDOffset As Long
  lngCalledIDNameSize As Long
  lngCalledIDNameOffset As Long
  lngConnectedIDFlags As Long
  lngConnectedIDSize As Long
  lngConnectedIDOffset As Long
  lngConnectedIDNameSize As Long
  lngConnectedIDNameOffset As Long
  lngRedirectionIDFlags As Long
  lngRedirectionIDSize As Long
  lngRedirectionIDOffset As Long
  lngRedirectionIDNameSize As Long
  lngRedirectionIDNameOffset As Long
  lngRedirectingIDFlags As Long
  lngRedirectingIDSize As Long
  lngRedirectingIDOffset As Long
  lngRedirectingIDNameSize As Long
  lngRedirectingIDNameOffset As Long
  lngAppNameSize As Long
  lngAppNameOffset As Long
  lngDisplayableAddressSize As Long
  lngDisplayableAddressOffset As Long
  lngCalledPartySize As Long
  lngCalledPartyOffset As Long
  lngCommentSize As Long
  lngCommentOffset As Long
  lngDisplaySize As Long
  lngDisplayOffset As Long
  lngUserUserInfoSize As Long
  lngUserUserInfoOffset As Long
  lngHighLevelCompSize As Long
  lngHighLevelCompOffset As Long
  lngLowLevelCompSize As Long
  lngLowLevelCompOffset As Long
  lngChargingInfoSize As Long
  lngChargingInfoOffset As Long
  lngTerminalModesSize As Long
  lngTerminalModesOffset As Long
  lngDevSpecificSize As Long
  lngDevSpecificOffset As Long
  ' Extra Data buffer
  vbByteBuffer(0 To 2048) As Byte
End Type
```

and

```
Public Type LINECALLPARAMS
    lngTotalSize As Long
    lngBearerMode As Long
    lngMinRate As Long
    lngMaxRate As Long
    lngMediaMode As Long
    lngCallParamFlags As Long
    lngAddressMode As Long
    lngAddressID As Long
    DialParams As LINEDIALPARAMS
    lngOrigAddressSize As Long
    lngOrigAddressOffset As Long
    lngDisplayableAddressSize As Long
    lngDisplayableAddressOffset As Long
    lngCalledPartySize As Long
    lngCalledPartyOffset As Long
    lngCommentSize As Long
    lngCommentOffset As Long
    lngUserUserInfoSize As Long
    lngUserUserInfoOffset As Long
    lngHighLevelCompSize As Long
    lngHighLevelCompOffset As Long
    lngLowLevelCompSize As Long
    lngLowLevelCompOffset As Long
    lngDevSpecificSize As Long
    lngDevSpecificOffset As Long
'#if (TAPI_CURRENT_VERSION >= 0x00020000)
    lngPredictiveAutoTransferStates As Long
    lngTargetAddressSize As Long
    lngTargetAddressOffset As Long
    lngSendingFlowspecSize As Long
    lngSendingFlowspecOffset As Long
    lngReceivingFlowspecSize As Long
    lngReceivingFlowspecOffset As Long
    lngDeviceClassSize As Long
    lngDeviceClassOffset As Long
    lngDeviceConfigSize As Long
    lngDeviceConfigOffset As Long
    lngCallDataSize As Long
    lngCallDataOffset As Long
    lngNoAnswerTimeout As Long
    lngCallingPartyIDSize As Long
    lngCallingPartyIDOffset As Long
'#End If
    vbByteBuffer(0 To 2047) As Byte
End Type
```

at the end of LINECALLPARAMS I now have a buffer at the end of the type declaration for the variable-length data.

```
vbByteBuffer(0 To 2047) As Byte
```

I then set the size parameter like this :-

```
typCallParams.lngTotalSize = Len(typCallParams)
```

and set up the sizes for the two telephone numbers I want to specify in the variable data part of the structure.

```
typCallParams.lngCallingPartyIDSize = 12
typCallParams.lngCalledPartySize = 12
```

One is for the telephone number I am calling, one is to set the caller ID information for the line that I am using.

Then I get the address of the whole structure in memory, and subtract it from the location in memory of the buffer part. Giving me an offset from the beginning of the structure.

```
Dim StartOfType As Long
Dim StartOfBufferOffset As Long
StartOfType = VarPtr(typCallParams) ' address
StartOfBufferOffset = VarPtr(typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(0)) - VarPtr(typCallParams)
```

Then I try to set some data in the buffer area.

```
'calling
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(0) = CByte("0")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(1) = CByte("1")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(2) = CByte("2")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(3) = CByte("3")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(4) = CByte("4")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(5) = CByte("1")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(6) = CByte("2")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(7) = CByte("3")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(8) = CByte("4")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(9) = CByte("5")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(10) = CByte("6")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(11) = CByte(0)

'called
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(112) = CByte("0")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(113) = CByte("1")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(114) = CByte("5")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(115) = CByte("4")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(116) = CByte("3")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(117) = CByte("6")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(118) = CByte("5")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(119) = CByte("4")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(120) = CByte("3")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(121) = CByte("2")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(122) = CByte("1")
typCallParams.vbByteBuffer(123) = CByte(0)
```

Then point the offsets :-

```
typCallParams.lngCallingPartyIDOffset = StartOfBufferOffset
typCallParams.lngCalledPartyOffset = StartOfBufferOffset + 112
```

Notice I intentionally left a big chunk of space between the two bits of information, and did the next offset 100 bytes onwards.

Then I do the API call.

```
lngResult = lineMakeCall(mlngLineHandle, mlngCallHandle, "", 0, typCallParams)
```

It's not quite there ... but I don't think we are too far off.

Any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: See the [Microsoft notes on calling C++ DLLs from VB6](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/vb5dll.asp)

Answer (score 1):

`TAPI` 2 that you described above is one of the hardest in design and memory management to be used from languages other than C/C++. Try using [TAPI 3.x](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms734215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is implemented based on COM technology and thus you can simply use it in `VB6`.